# Change the background of a div when a class is hovered and vice versa

Tags: html, css, class, background, background-color

I am working on a site and looking to change the background color of a div when a text class is hovered over.  I have the following HTML

```
<ul class="action-list-three">
<li class="three.footer">
<a class="provider" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</a><br />
</li>
</ul>
```

and the following CSS (want to change this BG Color):

```
.action-list-three a.provider {
background: #71CDF1;
padding-top: 5px;color: white;
margin-left: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-bottom: 35px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-right: 60px;
font-size: 20px;
border: rgb(30, 128, 167);
border-style: inset;
border-width: 2px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-left: 742px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;}
```

I know im probably missing some info, so can be viewed live at:
sandbox.petassure.com

thanks for any help

Comment: We need more details! Do you want to change the background of ul.action-list-three when the link is hovered over?

Comment: if you look on our sandbox site, i am attempting this:
when hovering over the light blue padding, the link text will change to white. when hovering over the link, the blue padding will turn to the darker blue, as when you hover over just the lighter blue padding


make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `:hover` declaration within CSS

```
.provider:hover{
   background: red;
}
```

JS Solution, very simple example

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/3423/

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").hover(function () {
        $("div").css("background-color", "red");
    }, function () {
        $("div").css("background-color", "white");
    });

    $("div").hover(function () {
        $(".test").css("background-color", "red");
    }, function () {
        $(".test").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Comment: Question says change the background of a div not hyperlink

Comment: If you wish to apply the hover effect to a div that isn't being hovered over and it also isn't a child of the hivered div, the you will need to use `javaScript`

Comment: is that very hard to implement. I am very limited in JS

Comment: I've given a javascript solution also

Comment: ive tried implementing the JS version on my site, but it is still not working. I got it to work in the DEMO editor, but it will not on my site. (replacing the appropriate fields of course)

Comment: Dont forget to include the `jQuery` library inside the <`head>` of your HTML document. Also, wrap the JS inside a `function` to ensure it only loads once the library has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here i edited it:

Html:

```
<ul class="action-list-three">
<li class="three.footer">
<a class="provider" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</a><br />
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.action-list-three a.provider {
background-color: #71CDF1;
padding-top: 5px;color: white;
margin-left: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-bottom: 35px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-right: 60px;
font-size: 20px;
border: rgb(30, 128, 167);
border-style: inset;
border-width: 2px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-left: 742px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;}

.action-list-three a.provider:hover{
background-color: WHAT COLOR YOU WANT
}
```

Just change the "WHAT COLOR DO YOU WANT"

Comment: You change for the color you want ?

Comment: yes, this only changes the color over the element. Not the secondary element like i am intending.

Comment: http://sandbox.petassure.com/ scroll down to footer area, hover over any of the subtext in the three blue boxes. That is the desired effect i am looking for, but in the entire padded area.